# Xamarin Listview iOS bug?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

someone has seen this bug in a Listview on iOS, the content is cut in half :(.

[image: bug sample]

[image: bug sample]

It does not always happen, if you leave the page and re-enter that no longer happens and the list is correctly seen on the entire screen

[image: Good one]

Comment: The only way anyone here can help you, is if you **show your code** in the question.

Comment: Change `CachingStrategy` if you set it as `RecycleElement` on ListView , refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49645504/8187800.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.